# Facebook app server side authentication (Java server with JavaScript client)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a Facebook application that will run in a FB Canvas. My server is a Java server, and I'm using JavaScript for client side.

Facebook asks for a URL that will be requested (POST) on application load. This URL should not be a dynamic URL (ends with '/' or contains '?'). So I wrote a servlet with URL: `http://localhost:8080/myApp` that will parse the `signed_request` param. Now I'm stuck on how to return the markup to the client, and then execute a client side requests to FB API. Is there more elegant way then just this servlet returns the markup? 
Notice that I cannot redirect (with 302) since the servlet runs from an iframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there more elegant way then just this servlet returns the markup?

More “elegant” in what regard?

Your servlet behaves as a web server here, and web servers usually answer HTTP requests by returning “markup” (HTML, CSS, JS, …) – at what point and how to you want your app to be “more elegant” than that?

> Notice that I cannot redirect (with 302) since the servlet runs from an iframe.

You mean the Facebook canvas iframe, or another iframe within that?

And where do you want to redirect to and why?

Comment: 1. There is more elegant way to response with a whole HTML file than REST API (servlet). For example, JSP. All I want is to parse the request from FB, check the user ID, and return markup according to the user ID. 2. I refer to FB canvas iframe. If I could redirect, I would redirect to the HTML instead of returning it in the servlet response. I hope that explain it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: To be more clarified - My goal is to get the user ID before loading the canvas.

Comment: You’ll get it “while” the canvas gets loaded, because the signed_request parameter is passed to your app while initially loading it into the iframe.